# Implementing certain sequence of JK flipflop to the circuit using tinkercad

Tags: circuit-design, integrated-circuit, power-electronics, flipflop

I am a beginner when it comes to electronics and what I'm trying to create is a circuit in which it outputs to the 3 LED (3 bits) the following sequence below using JK flip flop.

[image]

This is the picture [image: picture] of the one I'm doing. I'm using [tinkercad](https://www.tinkercad.com/things?type=circuits&view_mode=default)

You can access [my work here](https://www.tinkercad.com/embed/aRoQeMjtjqM?editbtn=1) if you want

Also, here's my computation which I'm pretty sure as I've triple checked it.

[image]

[image]

Though I'm very much familiar on how to arrive at the needed expression for each JK what I'm not familiar with is how to apply it to the actual circuit (in my case is the tinkercad).

**Update:**

The circuit diagram would be like below where the values of [J0,K0] to [J2,K2] are indicated above.

[image]

Also, someone sends me a picture of their schematic diagram and upon checking it, my tinkercad work seems identical to that.

[image]

How do I implement the "t", "en" and "0" on tinkercad 74HC73? Do you have any idea? I'm pertaining to this part of the circuit.

[image]

It seems that all the "t" and "en" from Q2 to Q0 are 0 while "en" is set to 1.

Comment: Where does the symbol for the flip-flop come from? Are you saying that it doesn't match the 74HC73? But then you are saying that the schematic does match your tinker work so I'm unsure what you mean. This is why EEs begin with the schematic and develop that to work with known chip pin outs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir, what I mean is my work in tinkercad matches the schematic diagram except for those "t", "en" and "0" because I don't have any idea on how to do it in tinkercad. Based on the pinouts of 74HC73 there are no "t", "en". "0" stands for CLR i believed, but the "t", "en" I don't have any idea. Therefore I'm unable to implement that part on tinkercad

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help, I've figured it out and it is now working.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that even though I'm only using the clock 1, clock 2 of the first 74HC73 and the clock 1 only of the second 74HC73 I  still need to connect the clock 2 of the second 74HC73 to the clock source.

Also I need to connect to the positive terminal the reset 2 of the second 74HC73 even if I'm not using it. Maybe its a bugged on the side of the tinkercad?

So, in summary:

From my previous circuit which is this

[image]

I changed it to look like this, just connecting the clock of the 2 74HC73 (the clock 1 and clock 2 for both of them) and also, connecting all the four reset to the positive side of the circuit.

[image]